# Homogenous ordinary equation - Homogeneous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

The question is:

$(x-y)dx + xdy = 0$

**Trying to solve:**

$
\\M(x,y) = (x-y)
\\N(x,y) = x
$

$
\\Kx - Ky = K(x-y) \Rightarrow \text{ Homogeneous}
\\Kx = K(x) \Rightarrow \text{Homogeneous}$

$
\\y = vx
\\dy = vdx+xdv$

$
\\(x-vx)dx+x(vdx+xdv)=0
\\xdx + x^2dv = 0
$

I'm stucked here. I know I have to integrate now. The answer is

$$x=e^{-y/x}+c$$ but I can't get there.

What I did is:

$$
\\x^2dv=-xdx
\\\int dv=-\int\frac{x}{x^2}dx
\\\int dv=-\int\frac{1}{x}dx
\\v+c_1=-ln(x)+c_2
\\\frac{y}{x}=-ln(x)+c_2-c_1
\\-x(ln(x)+c_2-c_1)=y
$$

And now? What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure the answer is $+c$ rather than $\times c$?

Comment: The answer should be $\times c$

Comment: Is there a way to know if this answer is right? For example, with this equation was exact, when I derivate the general solution I get the ODE. Is there a way to do that with homogeneous equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your notation earlier so I haven't checked it through, but at the end it's simple enough to rearrange your last line by dividing by $-x$ and then exponentiating. (Let $c=c_1-c_2$.) You get almost what you were looking for. (See my comment.)

---

Exponentiating means raising $e$ to the powers given. $$a=b \implies e^a=e^b$$ Note that $e^{\ln y}=y$.

Comment: I am sorry, but what do you mean with 'exponentiating' ? I felt that I need this concept to get my answer.

Comment: @Richard: Just the above, the $\exp$ map.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{HINT}$: Try the following:$$\frac{xdx}{x^2}=\frac{ydx-xdy}{x^2}=-d\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

Comment: :( ... Well, another hint?

Comment: Then, you get $d \left(\ln x\right)=-d \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ which finally gives you $\ln x=-y/x+c$

Answer (score 0):

try to solve it as exact equations as it can be made into the form of M(x,y) dx + N(x,y) dy by multiplying both sides with y

then check for exactness
if exact, solution is int( M dx) + uncommon terms from int (N dy)
if not exact multiply with suitable Integrating factor and then follow the steps for solving exact.